# How to use the letters "Q" and "A" inside a list in HTML

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set up a list in HTML or CSS to use specific letters instead of bullets?

Example:

```
Q. a question will be posted here.
A. the answer will go here.
```

I know I can go in and format each entry, but I would prefer to modify individual `<li>` tags with a class.

Comment: Yes you can, but what does your code look like now? And have you defined classes for answers/questions separately?

Comment: Why are you using `li` elements for each Q and each A?

Answer (score 21):

Semantically, a `<dl>` is a better fit for Q/A. You can use the [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element like so:

```css
dt:before {
  content: 'Q. ';
}
dd:before {
  content: 'A. ';
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Is this a question?</dt>
  <dd>Yes, it is.</dd>
</dl>
```

Note: According to [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) for `<dl>` (emphasis mine):

> Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, **questions and answers**, or any other groups of name-value data.

Comment: I wouldn't call it cheating, if anything it actually *makes sense* to use a `dl` compared to, say, using a straight (un)ordered list.

Comment: One thing to note, though, is that CSS content is not copyable (at least in some browsers). If you select the question and answer and hit copy, the Q: and A: will not be copied with the rest of the text.

Comment: If you want to align the answer with the question, just apply `margin-left: 0` to the `<dd>`.

Comment: CSS content isn't perceivable by most screen readers either, but here it wouldn't be a problem as definition lists are read as such by them. It would be a problem with (un)ordered lists or other elements, when in fact Q and A are very important part of the content and should be part of HTML code with an `<abbr title="Question">Q</abbr>` for the first occurence and then `<abbr>Q</abbr>` for other occurences... The problem with definition lists is that a question is not a term to be defined. They're only OK in glossaries and dictionaries

Comment: @FelipeAls - That's not quite true. According to the W3C, `dl` can be used for any [name-value pair or similar structure](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), so a Q&A structure is arguably semantic in a `dl`.

Comment: @FelipeAls according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), _"Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, **questions and answers**, or any other groups of name-value data._"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `:before` pseudo-selector like this:

```
li.question:before {
    content: "Q. ";
}
li.answer:before {
    content: "A. ";
}
```

Now you just apply classes `question` and `answer` to those `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `:nth-child` and `:before`.

```
li {
    list-style:none;
}   
li:nth-child(odd):before {
    content:"Q. "; 
}
li:nth-child(even):before {
    content:"A. "; 
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xt72Y/

It works with both `ol` and `ul` and does not require changing the html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include the key letters into list item contents:

```
<ul>
<li>Q. a question will be posted here.
<li>A. the answer will go here.
</ul>
```

and use `list-style-type: none` in CSS. Or, more reasonably, omit the `ul` markup and use just `p` markup for the items. The `ul` element is supposed to be used when it helps things, instead of being something that you must use for everything that remotely looks like a list.

It is also possible to make browsers display Q and A without including them into content proper, via CSS-generated content, but as they *are* part of the content, this would cause unnecessary problems when CSS is disabled or overridden.

Comment: I am not sure that "Q" and "A" marks are part of the content. I consider them more like a sort of visual aid (something like quotation marks for the quote etc.). The logic structure of the Q&A page remains understandable without them (especially when other visual aids, like more contrast font for questions, are present).

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to @Appleshell answer but doesn't loose the indent or text wrap formatting as a result of not needing to use `list-style:none;`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slyda/byqx542o/1/)

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    list-style-type: "Q. ";
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
    list-style-type: "A. ";
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

---

```
<p><strong>FAQ</strong>:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Why is this important?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad pri soleat verear habemus, porro feugiat quaerendum nam ut, id nibh soleat salutandi usu. Vim novum iracundia ad, nec ei erat explicari. Cu quo dissentiet complectitur necessitatibus. Ut ignota aliquam sit. Mea eu amet debet oratio, cum quando munere appareat ut. In semper ancillae sea, ius ad equidem evertitur. Eam summo quaestio ne, eu sea quando aliquid accusam.</li>
  <li>What should I do next?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad pri soleat verear habemus, porro feugiat quaerendum nam ut, id nibh soleat salutandi usu. Vim novum iracundia ad, nec ei erat explicari. Cu quo dissentiet complectitur necessitatibus. Ut ignota aliquam sit. Mea eu amet debet oratio, cum quando munere appareat ut. In semper ancillae sea, ius ad equidem evertitur. Eam summo quaestio ne, eu sea quando aliquid accusam.</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

---

Second [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slyda/d38jy56u/1/) example using class name.